# What happens when a world chess champion doesn't defend their title?

Tags: rules, fide, world-championship, carlsen, candidates

When a world chess champion like Carlsen decides not to defend the title, how does FIDE determine who the new champion will be? Is it just the winner of the Candidates tournament?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry for the drive-by downvote with zero explanation by someone. Please persist with us

Comment: -1 no research effort - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2023.

Comment: The wikipedia page doesn't explain why the WC title doesn't automatically go to Nepo, since there is no "World Champion" to play.

Comment: @qwr The question isn't why the FIDE decides this or that, but just how the new World Champion is chosen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The winner of the candidates plays a WC match against the runner-up of the candidates. The World Champion who does not defend the title loses the title to one of these two players.
Therefore, the next World Champion after Carlsen will be Nepo or Ding.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that when Fischer refused to defend his title in 1975, the title instantly went to Karpov. No WCC took place that year, although the match between Korchnoi and Karpov that had just happened could retroactively be called the WCC.